# d3.js: How to size D3 partition table based on both children and parents value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, partition

I am trying to build a basic icicle partition tree in D3 and I can't seem to get the value function to do what I want. Basically, I want each node to be sized according to it's value and the sum of it's children. As mentioned in:
[d3.js: size of parents = sum of size of children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125586/d3-js-size-of-parents-sum-of-size-of-children), the default behavior sizes nodes according to the sum of the children. However, I've found that it only looks at the leaf nodes and then all nodes are sized according to those.

I have hard-coded the values that I wish my nodes to be sized as JSON values (totalMass) which has already computed the value of the current node and it's children. The result is below:

*Sorry, I can't post an image but I can describe it:*

```js
What I would like:

Root (12 = 5 + Children (3+4))
    Child1 (3 = 1 + Children (2))
        Leaf (2)
    Child2 (4 = 2 + Children (2))
        Leaf (2)
        
What I get:

Root (4)
    Child1 (2)
        Leaf (2)
    Child2 (2)
        Leaf (2)
```

Thanks for your help.
So, what I wish is for everything to be sized proportionally to the root node's actual value, thus there will be some empty spaces (as each node's value will be higher than the sum of it's children). This is also a simplified example as for my actual data, not all leaf nodes will not be on the same level.

Is there anyway to get the value function to work like this, or will I have to manually size my chart nodes?

Here is my code so far (in Typescript):

```js
this.svg = d3.select(this.container).append("svg")
            .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.right + this.margin.left)
            .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");          

        this.rectPartition = this.svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")")
            .classed("rect_partition", true);

        // TODO: filter children such that accounts for leaf children of same category
        this.partition = d3.layout.partition()
            .children((d: ChartNode) => {
                var filteredChildren = [];
                if (d.children) {
                    d.children.forEach(child => {
                        if (this.nodeContainsCategory(child, ProductsCategory)) filteredChildren.push(child);
                    });
                    return filteredChildren;
                }
                else return null;
            })
            .value((d: ChartNode) => d.totalMass)
            .sort((a: ChartNode, b: ChartNode) => {
                //first sort by owner, then sort by short name
                if (a.owner === b.owner) return (a.shortName > b.shortName) ? 1 : -1;
                else return (a.owner > b.owner) ? 1 : -1;
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm having the same problem as you to be honest. Apparently there's a pull request working on this issue: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/574. And there's another solution described Mike Bostock himself on the thread's comments using dummy nodes. I'm still trying to work this around but maybe if you take a look might help you on this (if you still have this problem).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - haven't looked at this problem for a while. Just checked out the pull request you posted and apparently the desired behavior has been implemented in d3-hierarchy for 4.0.

Answer (score -1):

I think Zoomable Bubble Chart is best fitted according to your requirement. you can use the d3 pack layout for this.

here is the Official D3 link for this construct..
[Click here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535)

I hope my recommendation will help you..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would still like to maintain the structured hierarchy of a partition tree.